# MYSQL Update by condition in Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is the MySQL version Syntax:

```
UPDATE table1 
    JOIN (
            SELECT mId, COUNT(*) c 
            FROM table1 
            GROUP BY mId 
            HAVING c < 2
        ) t1 
USING (mId)
    SET shared=0 ;
```

This means that if a value of mId only appears once in the mId column, then set shared = 0.

How to rewrite it in PHP code igniter?

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to write in Code-igniter.

Comment: Stuck here:
      $this->db->update('table1', ????);

Comment: have you tried this ? [Codeigniter 3 documentation - Queries](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html)

use `$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');`